# Wordpress multi-language no plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am working on a wordpress site and I need to implement multiple-languages function (i don't want to use any plugin, just pure programming). I created 2 folders (en/de) and put index.php in each one of them. The problem I am confrunting now is that I want to shows pages in specific language. Example:
For en:

```
www.domain.com/en/example
```

For de:

```
www.domain.com/de/beispiel
```

Where Beispiel = example . I did the rewrite rules needed for this using `add_rewrite_rule()` function, but how can I get the page from the database only if the language coresponds to a column where the language is set for every post?
PS: I added one more column for pages table,in order to tell for what language are written.
My intention is to write a custom query inside index.php , which will get specified page from the table by `pagename` and `current language`. How can I do this?

UPDATE 1:
I found a solution , but I do not know if it is recommended. In my theme's index.php I chnaged

```
global $post;
    $i = 0;
    while ( have_posts() && $post->language == 'en') {
        
        $i++;
        if ( $i > 1 ) {
                echo '<hr class="post-separator styled-separator is-style-wide section-inner" aria-hidden="true" />';
        }
         the_post();
        
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

    }
```

Where `$post->language` is the field from mysql table where the language is stored.